# Swift UIDatePicker restrict future year not month and date

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

`datePicker.maximumDate = Date()`

Will disable future date
I want to restrict future year only.user can select future month and date.
How to do this.any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set the maximum date to the latest day in your picker, what you mean by restrict the future year only, that you wanna keep the same day and month, and allow only to incremente the year?

Comment: yes.i want to allow increment future month and day. not year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: Date())
guard let maximumDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: currentYear + 1))?.addingTimeInterval(-1) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't get next year")
}
picker.maximumDate = maximumDate
print(picker.maximumDate ?? "")
```

The maximum date should be `December 31st, 2018 at 23:59:59` in your date picker.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the `UIDatePicker` to only allow future dates in the current year, you can construct a `Date` object corresponding to the start of next year and use that as the `maximumDate`.

```
let thisYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
datePicker.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: thisYear+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the current date and extract the year from it. (Use the Calendar function `date(from:)`.) Create DateComponents for 31 December of that year. Use that to create a Date. Make that the maximum date for the date picker. That will let the user pick any date in the current year, but not advance the year.